# Use conditionnal Image showing with react native

Tags: react-native

I would like show this photo only if post.photo is not null

I tried this but not working, can you help me

```
<Image key={i + 'photopost'} source={post.photo ? { uri: 'https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png'}} />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this way

```
{post.photo ? 
  <Image key={i + 'photopost'} source={{ uri: 'https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png'}} /> 
: null}
```

or

```
{post.photo && 
  <Image key={i + 'photopost'} source={{ uri: 'https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png'}} />}
```

Comment: @kevin please accept answer if it helps thanks :-)

Comment: *its also possible to do it with a && conditional if you don't want to use a ternary operator.

This is down to preference though.

Comment: I will try your solutions tonight but seems good, thanks